# Vue.js components capitalized

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

is there a specific reason for Vue.js components being capitalized?

I see this a lot but I don't see a valid reason for why there are written this way. Even the cli repositories have this for components.

Comment: any examples? ?

Comment: @MU https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/tree/master/template/src/components .vue files always seem to be written with a capital letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a convention to differentiate between the component constructor/definition (capitalised) and the component instances.

It's a common convention that classes are capitalised but instances of a class are not:

```
const user = new User()
```

Answer (score 5):

React/React-Native Developers are used to capitalizing components because of the Class based component architecture. So they tend to carry that over to Vue.

The Vue engine itself doesn't care, it interprets both just fine. Find a convention and stick to it. You're fine either way, just be consistent.

My personal convention is to Capitalize components that I make myself (components folder) this way I can differentiate better between my own components and Vuetify components for example.

```
<v-row class="mt-10">    // Vuetify component
   <v-col cols="12">
      <CustomTeapot />   // My component
   </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Answer (score 4):

From what I have seen and used, vuejs doesn't mind your component files', component names' case.

Example:

```
// HelloWorld.vue   
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Hello'
    }
  }
}
```

if used in say App.vue like:

```
//App.vue
<template>
  <HelloWorld></HelloWorld>
  <hello-world><hello-world>
</template>
 
import HelloWorld from 'path/to/HelloWorld' //adding .vue is optional

export default {
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
```

There would be absolutely no negative consequences, vuejs doesn't enforce W3C standards

> Note that Vue does not enforce the W3C rules for custom tag names (all-lowercase, must contain a hyphen) though following this convention is considered good practice.
>
> [source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Registration)

So you can use an imported component in kebab-case or camelCase vuejs internally checks for it and would render the component the same way.